# Why does this think it's correct?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and I have this very simple code. It's supposed to be a login, and it's not working. I don't need any tips on making it better, I'm planning to do that when this starts to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> Sign-in  </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var em = prompt("Enter E-mail Here:")
        if(em = "I hid this to prevent spam"){
            var pa = prompt("Enter Password Here:")
                if(pa = "jct28if5"){
                    alert("Welcome!")
                 }
                else{
                    alert("Incorrect password!")
        }
    }
        else {
            alert("Invalid e-mail!")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What it's doing now is no matter what, it thinks that the correct e-mail and password were used. Could somebody help?

Comment: `if(pa = "jct28if5")` will always be true. You need to use a comparison operator, not assignment.

Comment: Use `===`, not `=` in the condition. `if(pa === "jct28if5"){`

Comment: *=* should be *==* or *===*

Comment: If you check your code in http://www.jshint.com/ you'll get an error -- "Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment."

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your code up a bit. Some things to note.

You can't just put raw content in the `<head>`.

Your password is in the raw source of the page, so anyone can view the page source and see what the correct password is. That's an absolutely horrible design. Passwords should be passed to server side where they're checked for validity.

In C like programming language such as Javascript, == tests for equality and will return a boolean. The = sign assigns a value to a variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Sign-in
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var em = prompt("Enter E-mail Here:")
        if(em == "I hid this to prevent spam"){
            var pa = prompt("Enter Password Here:")
                if(pa == "jct28if5"){
                    alert("Welcome!")
                 }
                else{
                    alert("Incorrect password!")
        }
    }
        else {
            alert("Invalid e-mail!")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed

```
var em = prompt("Enter E-mail Here:")
            if(em === "I hid this to prevent spam"){
                var pa = prompt("Enter Password Here:")
                    if(pa === "jct28if5"){
                        alert("Welcome!")
                     }
                    else{
                        alert("Incorrect password!")
            }
        }
            else {
                alert("Invalid e-mail!")
    }
```

You use a single = when you're assigning a variable a value. like var x = 1.
But if you want to check equality, use ===. like if(x ===1)

Answer (score 0):

Just one addition:

== checks value
=== checks value and type

Someone who deactivates js or doesn't support it like curl/wget and others, will not be stopped by this, except you load the whole website with js, what might be stupid cause of search engines might not index the content though.

Hope this helps.